# How to get values from autoincrements from a table and use it in relation to another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to php en msq sql en made a form to add to a database.I have 3 tables with 3 autoincrements,if it could i would have had 5. I wonder if its possible to get an autoincrement value  from a table and apply it to another. I have betaling and adresgegevens increments which i want to be linked with klantgegevens, but if i try to add my form to my database i get this.

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in.

Furthermore i used 3 sql statements if i drop the 3th i can insert the form without a problem but thats not what i want.

Any other solutions are very welcome.
this is my php code

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["submit3"])){

$verbinding = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=ziggo2","root","usbw");

$sql1=" 
INSERT INTO betaling (order_id,rekeningnr,basispakket,voordeel)
 VALUES (:order_id,:rekeningnr,:basispakket,:voordeel);
";       
$statement = $verbinding ->prepare($sql1);
$statement->bindValue(":order_id", '', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":rekeningnr", $_SESSION['rekeningnr'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$statement->bindValue(":basispakket", '50', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":voordeel", $_SESSION['voordeel'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
$count1 = $statement->rowCount();


$sql2="
INSERT INTO adresgegevens (adres_id,postcode,huisnr,straat,plaats,datum)
VALUES(:adres_id,:postcode,:huisnr,:straat,:plaats,:datum);
";
  $statement = $verbinding ->prepare($sql2);
$statement->bindValue(":adres_id", '', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":postcode", $_SESSION['postcode'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":huisnr", $_SESSION['huisnr'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":straat", $_SESSION['straat'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":plaats", $_SESSION['plaats'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":datum", '', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
$count2 = $statement->rowCount();

$sql3=" 
JOIN adresgegevens a on a.adres_id = k.adres_id JOIN klantgegevens k on k.order_id = b.order_id JOIN betaling where klantgegevens k = k.klantnr
INSERT INTO klantgegevens(klantnr,adres_id,order_idgeslacht,voorletters,tussenvoegsel,achternaam,gebdat,e-mail,telnr,producten)
VALUES (:klantnr,:adres_id,:order_id,:geslacht,:voorletters,:tussenvoegsel,:achternaam,:gebdat,:e-mail,:telnr,:producten);
";
$statement = $verbinding ->prepare($sql3);
$statement->bindValue(":klantnr", '', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":adres_id", '' , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":order_id",  '', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":geslacht", $_SESSION['geslacht'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":voorletters", $_SESSION['voorletters'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":tussenvoegsel", $_SESSION['tussenvoegsel'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":achternaam", $_SESSION['achternaam'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":gebdat", $_SESSION['gebdat'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":e-mail", $_SESSION['e-mail'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":telnr", $_SESSION['telnr'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":producten", $_SESSION['producten'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
$count3 = $statement->rowCount();

//  SET @lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID();


if($count1 == 1 AND $count2 == 1 AND $count3 == 1){
 print("Er is $count1 rij succesvol toegevoegd.");
}
 else{
    print("OOps er is wat fout gegaan"); 
 }

//if strlen( $count => 1){
//  print("U heeft" . $count . "regel toegevoegd");
//}

    }
?>
```

Comment: I fixed your code markup, but please take some time and clean up your question a little. There are a lot of typos and your code looks quite messy. Also, check if we actually need your entire code, because people are less likely to answer, if they need to read a whole block of foreign code. Anyway, welcome on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: Read (and fix) the warning reported - "Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.." then move on. Every little trivial-fixed issue doesn't make for an SO question (and mixing such into the real question leads for unfocused questions).

Comment: And as to your question, take a look at [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). This method can give you the last automatically inserted ID that was created on the current connection. Note that it has to be called on the PDO object, not on the PDOStatement.

Answer (score 0):

The trick you need is the MySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

This evaluates to the most recently used autoincrement id.

You can retrieve it into your client (php) program using the query

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS last_id
```

The function `PDO::lastInsertId()` is a shortcut for this.

You can also use it in a sequence of INSERT or UPDATE statements. For example:

```
INSERT INTO name (surname, given, title) VALUES ( :sur, :giv, :title )
INSERT INTO address (name_id, street, city) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), :street, :city)
```

Why does this work, even on a busy database with many connections? Because MySQL maintains values for LAST_INSERT_ID() in the context for each distinct connection.